# Convergence of the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k} |x-y_k|^{-\alpha}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Suppose $S=\{y_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is a countable dense subset of the open unit ball $B(0,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. We write
\begin{equation}
u(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k} |x-y_k|^{-\alpha} \quad \forall x\in B(0,1) \backslash S,
\end{equation}
where $\alpha$ is a positive real number.

1) Is the series convergent? If so, in what sense? Is the series uniformly convergent?

I think the series is convergent a.e by the integral test. However, I'm not sure about the uniform convergence.

2) I would like to find the weak (first) derivative of $u$, but do I need uniform convergence to differentiate under the summation?

Thank you.

Comment: Choose $\alpha$ such that the derivative of $|x-x_k|^{-\alpha}$ is in $L^1$ and use any tool like the Monotone Convergence Theorem.